# Quest UI Display in Unity 2D

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, gui, quests

I have this quest manager script where I store all my quests for easy duplication.

[image]

I'm adding a feature that gives the player the option to see his/her current to-do quest.

The first thing I tried was just showing it in my dialogue box(which closes immediately because it's supposed to be for dialogues only).

Now I made a quest log UI so he/she can see his/her current to-do list with a claim button for the reward.

All I need to do now is to change the text I have in the quest log UI (the Quest Title and the Description) the same way I was doing with the dialogue for each quests, but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
public QuestObject[] quests;
public bool[] questCompleted;

public DialogueManager theDM;
public PanelManager thePM;

public string itemCollected;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    questCompleted = new bool[quests.Length];
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void ShowQuestText(string questText)
{
    theDM.dialogLines = new string[1];
    theDM.dialogLines[0] = questText;

    theDM.currentLine = 0;
    theDM.ShowDialogue();
}
public void ShowQuestList()
{
    thePM.ShowDialogue();
}
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
public class QuestObject : MonoBehaviour {

public int questNumber;

public QuestManager theQM;
public DialogueManager donMariano;

public string startText;
public string endText;

public string questTitle;
public string questDescription;
public int rewardGold;
public int rewardChilli;
public int rewardEggplant;
public int rewardPotato;

public bool isItemQuest;
public string targetItem;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(isItemQuest)
    {
        if(theQM.itemCollected == targetItem)
        {
            theQM.itemCollected = null;

            EndQuest();
        }
    }
}
public void StartQuest()
{
    theQM.ShowQuestText(startText);

}
public void EndQuest()
{
    theQM.ShowQuestText(endText);
    theQM.questCompleted[questNumber] = true;
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

}

```
public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject dBox;
    public Text dText;

    public bool dialogActive;
    public string[] dialogLines;
    public int currentLine;

    public Image[] dialogImage;

    private PlayerControl thePlayer;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerControl>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if(dialogActive && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            currentLine++;
        }
        if(currentLine >= dialogLines.Length)
        {
            dBox.SetActive(false);
            dialogActive = false;

            currentLine = 0;
            thePlayer.canMove = true;
        }
        dText.text = dialogLines[currentLine];
    }
    public void ShowBox(string dialogue)
    {
        dialogActive = true;
        dBox.SetActive(true);
        dText.text = dialogue;
    }
    public void ShowDialogue()
    {
        dialogActive = true;
        dBox.SetActive(true);
        thePlayer.canMove = false;
    }
}
```

[image]